# How to deal with path to open files when deploying a Python App in Google Cloud?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying a Python Application to Google Cloud App Engine. All the code happens in *main.py* but it uses CSV files from a */data* folder.
Locally in my virtual environment, what I do is:

```
PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
df = pd.read_csv(PATH+"\\data\\mydata.csv")
```

But I fear this might not work once deployed, what is the right way to open the CSV files?

Answer (score 1):

I tried with:

```
PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
df = pd.read_csv(PATH+"/data/mydata.csv")
```

and it worked both locally and once deployed.

Just for the record, you need to deploy them in GAE Flexible, as Standard can't use libraries with code compiled in C [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#standard_environment_languages_and_runtimes) and Pandas is one of those cases.

> *[From 1]* You can use third-party libraries that are pure Python code with no C extensions
>
> *[From 2]* The interpreter cannot load Python services with C code; it is a "pure" Python environment.